# Detection device for robots

Tags: robotics, detection, distance

I am an electrical engineering student and I have been in robotics since 2019. I want to create my own robots and I need advise on a detection device.

Context :
The match happens on a 1m×2m table, 2 teams face each other and each team has 2 robots. If your robot hits another one you get disqualified. In order to ease detection you can place a 10cmx10cm device on top of enemy robots (at a fixed height). It means I need to create something in my robot that will detect the small devices I put on top of ennemy robots.

I was thinking of having a emitting IR "on enemy" device together with an IR 360° reception on my robot and use IR amplitudes to calculate angle and distance of the 2 enemy robots

But I think this solution is prone to blur and on a match day there might be a lot of bright lights aiming at the table and generating a lot of IR blur; also, even without blur the technology isn't very precise.

I was thinking of lasers with a streering mechanism but they aim in a  very specific direction and I might need a broader spectrum to be able to detect my device on the enemy robot, not just being precise with the distance. However, this technology can be very interesting if another tech can get me a precise angle to aim at.

I take any advice, even on expensive tech, because I can probably craft a cheap version.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of fun.  When two robots collide, how do you decide which one is disqualified?  When a robot is disqualified does it get romoved from the table?  Or just immobilised? Do you win by having last robot on the table?

Comment: LIDAR, Sonar, and IR sensors are all optoins for robot detection. Personally I'd go for Lidar as there are many hobbiest set ups for it ready to go

Comment: I wonder what resources you have?  I mean do you have 3d printing?  A lathe or mill?  And I presume it's for academic grades: do you get most credit for software?  Electronics?  "engineering tradeoffs"?  Or just winning?

Comment: I'm no expert in this but I think you may need a laser scanner like this. 
https://www.sick.com/at/en/safety-laser-scanners/c/g569359?q=:Def_Type:ProductFamily

Usually you need sensors such as laser scanner, ultrasonic and camera on the robot assuming its a mobile robot . Have you tried using a camera if you can do vision?

Comment: @jonathanjo usually when robots collide one is not moving while the other one pushes, disqualified means you score 0 points so your opponent wins

Comment: When I was in the university in the early 2000s I helped the robotics team to design their robot for sumo robots tournament. I remember that we used two-way sensing mechanism for enemy detection: Optical first for crude detection (to adjust orientation) and ultrasonic for distance measurement for attack strategy. Memories... Anyway, ultrasonic or sonar might fit your needs here.

Comment: I feel like the laser scan / LIDAR doesn't use the device you can put on top of your opponent robots, so how can I determine wether im detecting a robot or a random wall

Comment: I have access to all kind of manufacturing as long as it does not cost 1k euros for 1 piece

Comment: I think sonar and ultrasonic can be interesting but do you guys know how noise sensible the technology are ? In this range of frequencies I can expect a lot of blur on the table

Comment: @AmitM I ruled out cameras and video processing because it looks like it relies on parameters that will be totally different on match day (very bright lights, etc.). Also I would need to spend a lot of coding time to produce a low quality algorithm

Comment: Do you lose if you hit your teammate?  How big are the robots?

Comment: Hitting a teammate is tolerated but it very rarely happens. The two robots share the same perimeter max value but we can say they are both around 25cmx25cm

Comment: Strategy for an easy (if unsportsmanlike) win: just have your robot stand still. If it's not moving then it can't *cause* a collision with any other robot so any collision must come from an 'enemy' - which would then automatically disqualify the enemy ....

Comment: Lead cubes 10cm across.  It won't help detect your opponent's robots, but it will make them slower, and so top heavy that they fall over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Match](https://www.coupederobotique.fr/wp-content/uploads/Eurobot2023_Rules_FR_BETA.pdf) like [this](https://www.eurobot.org/)?

Along with others systems ... for "safety" ...

On your robot, it is advisable to envisage a "mobile rotary system" (rotating mirror) or "static rotating" (LEDs strip IR or [this](https://www.befr.ebay.be/itm/184387783568?hash=item2aee5e4b90:g:aVUAAOSwm39fW6P6&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoLO%2B%2B0aEXwo2IQeZK2lT8Hs93oeenfzpDIviSkkklwnyLuUEkmv4iuuDXwgD8ZkHnfqpBU9pvxAJ1H4vNxsYPvAIQVPb6T0cSsg498XGRng9zV0zGrajrJBwP%2F9ZYxCRbJUCZCJ8utY3fb6QCagwrcyBHhT3iEMexVbTdlue35rcc7Ca7H3GipueJ6%2FXtluBIs47hMrZ%2FNuPDofL6t3rJ7k%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR5i5kfvtYA)) (modulated with known rapid sequence (remember you will be surrounded by literally very big "noise"), like VOR type in aviation with reference points).
On your "adversary", a passive mirror system (all directions, circular like [this](https://www.shelbyoutdoor.com/product_info.php?products_id=2470&language=en)) that resends the received beam back in your direction (passive set of orthogonal mirrors or other known processes, such as used with "road reflection"). See [this](http://subaru.univ-lemans.fr/AccesLibre/UM/Pedago/physique/02/optigeo/miroirs3.html).
Thanks to this information, you can locate yourself and locate other "targets".
Not all reference points will always be visible.
You will therefore have to "keep" the previous measurements to locate yourself, even without "references".

Comment: Very interesting, I'll gather addionnal info on this technology. I will use lasers and encoded motors to locate myself on the table so the detection device doesn't have to keep track of where the robot is

Comment: Ok for encode motors. But another mean of locating (in case of ... ) is "always" necessary. I remember that you can use 2 reference points in your side corners of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for lidar or radar, then the best device to put on the opposing robots would be a corner-cube reflector.  The nature of that reflector should match the signal you're transmitting, e.g. mirrors or metal plates.

Lidar can have problems if the target either isn't reflective, or if it's too shiny and reflects the beam away from your sensor.  A corner cube would ensure a strong return.

Radar similarly gives a much stronger response from a corner cube, helping you to distinguish it from other random objects nearby.

Answer (score 0):

I always wanted to try a spinning laser beam for this kind of thing.  I'm imagining something like a 1 mw laser pointer with a spinning front-surface dental mirror, arranged like a ambulance light or lighthouse reflector.  To reduce tolerances, consider a very slight diverging lens somewhere so the beam is a few degrees.

You put this on the enemy robot and it should give you a very good target, which you can detect with very simple photo sensors to get direction.  You know it's your beacon because you know the period; it's a laser so it should be very saturating on your detectors.  You don't need accurate direction because the playing table is pretty small.

Alternatively, retroreflective material on the target, spinning laser on your robot, with some kind of rotation measurer ("zero-degree blip"), and omnidirectional photosensor.

Of course, you could spin the whole laser (with batteries), which might be easier to build.

[image]